# Bukkit cant heal player using console

Tags: java, bukkit

I want to heal a player using console. I am using bukkit 1.8.3. When i try and heal it using my code i get a error. I tried searching the internet it says because the console is not a player and i know that i removed all player. and replaced with a message or sender. Still the same error.

```
package me.herobrine112211.ulticmdpack;

import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.ChatColor;
import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.event.player.PlayerJoinEvent;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

public class System extends JavaPlugin implements Listener{

    public void onEnable() {
        getConfig().options().copyDefaults(true);
        saveConfig();
        Bukkit.getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(this, this);
        Bukkit.getServer().getLogger().info("Ultimate Command Pack Plugin has been actived!");
    }

    public void onDisable() {
        Bukkit.getServer().getLogger().info("Ultimate Command Pack Plugin has been disabled! This will give big problems to server.");
    }

    @EventHandler
    public void onPlayerJoin(PlayerJoinEvent joinevent){
        Player getplayer = joinevent.getPlayer();
        getplayer.sendMessage(ChatColor.AQUA + "Hey " + getplayer.getName() + "! Welcome to the Ultimate Prison server!");
        if(getplayer.getName().equals("Herobrine112211")){
            Bukkit.getServer().broadcastMessage(ChatColor.WHITE + "[" + ChatColor.GOLD + "BROADCAST" + ChatColor.WHITE + "] " + ChatColor.GOLD + "Server Creator Herobrine112211 has joined the game!!!!!!!!!!");
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String commandLabel, String[] args){


        Player player = (Player) sender;

            if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("contactowner")) {
                if (!sender.hasPermission("contactowner")){
                    sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Access denied.");
                    return true;
                }
                if (!(sender instanceof Player)) {
                    sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Console will never need owner support.");
                    return true;
                }
                player.sendMessage(ChatColor.GOLD + "Owner: Herobrine112211. Live chat skype: gangsteris33.");
            }

            if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("reloadconfig")){
                if (!sender.hasPermission("config.reload")){
                    sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Access denied.");
                    return true;
                }
                reloadConfig();
                sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Server config reloaded successfully.");
                return true;
            }

            if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("saveconfig")){
                if (!sender.hasPermission("config.save")){
                    sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Access denied.");
                    return true;
                }
                reloadConfig();
                sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Server config saved successfully.");
                return true;
            }

            if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("fakeop")) {
                if (!sender.hasPermission("fake.op")){
                    sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Access denied.");
                    return true;
                }
                if (args.length == 0) {
                    sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Please specify a player!");
                    return true;
                }
                Player target = Bukkit.getServer().getPlayer(args[0]);
                if (target == null) {
                    sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Player must be online!");
                    return true;
                }
                target.sendMessage(ChatColor.YELLOW + "You are now op!");
            }

            if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("fakejoin")) {
                if (!sender.hasPermission("fake.join")){
                    sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Access denied.");
                    return true;
                }
                if (args.length == 0) {
                    sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Please specify a name!");
                    return true;
                }
                Bukkit.getServer().broadcastMessage(ChatColor.YELLOW + args[0] + " joined the game.");
            }

            if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("broadcast")) {
                if (!sender.hasPermission("broadcast")){
                    sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Access denied.");
                    return true;
                }
                if (args.length == 0) {
                    sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Please give a message to broadcast!");
                    return true;
                }
                StringBuilder strbl = new StringBuilder();
                for(int i = 0; i < args.length; i++){
                    strbl.append(args[i] + " ");
                }
                String broadcastas = strbl.toString();
                Bukkit.getServer().broadcastMessage(ChatColor.WHITE + "[" + ChatColor.GOLD + "BROADCAST" + ChatColor.WHITE + "] " + ChatColor.RED + broadcastas);
            }

            if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("heal")) {
                if (!sender.hasPermission("heal")){
                    sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Access denied.");
                    return true;
                }
                if (!(sender instanceof Player)) {
                    if (args.length == 0) {
                        sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Please specify a player!");
                        return true;
                }
                    Player target = Bukkit.getServer().getPlayer(args[0]);
                    if (target == null) {
                        sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Player must be online to be healed!");
                            return true;
                    }
                    target.setHealth(20);
                    target.setFireTicks(0);
                    target.sendMessage(ChatColor.GREEN + "CONSOLE" + " healed you!");
                    sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.GREEN + "Player is healed!");
                    return true;
                }
                    if (args.length == 0) {
                            player.setHealth(20);
                            player.setFireTicks(0);
                            player.sendMessage(ChatColor.GREEN + "Your health is now full!");
                            return true;
                    }
                    Player target = Bukkit.getServer().getPlayer(args[0]);
                    if (target == null) {
                        sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Player must be online to be healed!");
                            return true;
                    }
                    target.setHealth(20);
                    target.setFireTicks(0);
                    target.sendMessage(ChatColor.GREEN + player.getName() + " healed you!");
                    player.sendMessage(ChatColor.GREEN + target.getName() + " is healed!");
            }

            if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("feed")) {
                if (!sender.hasPermission("feed")){
                    player.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Access denied.");
                    return true;
                }
                if (!(sender instanceof Player)) {
                    if (args.length == 0) {
                        sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Please specify a player!");
                        return true;
                }
                    Player target = Bukkit.getServer().getPlayer(args[0]);
                    if (target == null) {
                        sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Player must be online to be fed!");
                            return true;
                    }
                    target.setHealth(20);
                    target.setFireTicks(0);
                    target.sendMessage(ChatColor.GREEN + "CONSOLE" + " fed you!");
                    sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.GREEN + "Player hunger is now full!");
                    return true;
                }
                if (args.length == 0) {
                        player.setFoodLevel(20);
                        player.sendMessage(ChatColor.GREEN + "Your hunger is now full!");
                        return true;
                }
                Player target = Bukkit.getServer().getPlayer(args[0]);
                if (target == null) {
                    player.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Player must be online to be fed!");
                        return true;
                }
                target.setFoodLevel(20);
                target.sendMessage(ChatColor.GREEN + player.getName() + " fed you!");
                player.sendMessage(ChatColor.GREEN + target.getName() + " hunger is now full!");
        }
        return true;
   }
}
```

Can someone fix this code from me and paste the new one to copy? i need this fixed. I tried fixing my self a lot of times nothing worked.

Error log requested:

```
10:39:14 AM [WARN] Unexpected exception while parsing console command "heal Herobrine112211"
10:39:14 AM org.bukkit.command.CommandException: Unhandled exception executing command 'heal' in plugin UltimateCommandPack v1.0.5
10:39:14 AM at org.bukkit.command.PluginCommand.execute(PluginCommand.java:46) ~[bukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-61ef214]
10:39:14 AM at org.bukkit.command.SimpleCommandMap.dispatch(SimpleCommandMap.java:140) ~[bukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-61ef214]
10:39:14 AM at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_8_R2.CraftServer.dispatchCommand(CraftServer.java:625) ~[bukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-61ef214]
10:39:14 AM at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_8_R2.CraftServer.dispatchServerCommand(CraftServer.java:611) [bukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-61ef214]
10:39:14 AM at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R2.DedicatedServer.aN(DedicatedServer.java:372) [bukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-61ef214]
10:39:14 AM at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R2.DedicatedServer.A(DedicatedServer.java:337) [bukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-61ef214]
10:39:14 AM at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R2.MinecraftServer.z(MinecraftServer.java:626) [bukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-61ef214]
10:39:14 AM at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R2.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:534) [bukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-61ef214]
10:39:14 AM at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.7.0_75]
10:39:14 AM Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_8_R2.command.ColouredConsoleSender cannot be cast to org.bukkit.entity.Player
10:39:14 AM at me.herobrine112211.ulticmdpack.System.onCommand(System.java:39) ~[?:?]
10:39:14 AM at org.bukkit.command.PluginCommand.execute(PluginCommand.java:44) ~[bukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-61ef214]
10:39:14 AM ... 8 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting an error because you're trying to cast a `ColouredConsoleSender` to a `Player`.

To fix this, you should only cast the `sender` to a `Player` when

```
if(sender instanceof Player)
```

So, you should remove this line:

```
Player player = (Player) sender
```

And only use it once you have checked if `sender instanceof Player`. So, you could do something like this:

```
public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String commandLabel, String[] args){
    if(!(sender instanceof Player)){
        return false;
    }
    else{
        Player player = (Player) sender;

        //code...
    }
}
```

If you also wanted to allow for the console to run the commands, you could just only use `Player player = (Player) sender` once you have checked that `sender instanceof Player`.

So, for example:

```
public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String commandLabel, String[] args){

  if(cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("heal"){
    if(sender instanceof Player){
      Player player = (Player) sender;
      if(args.length > 0){
        Player target = Bukkit.getServer().getPlayer(args[0]);
        target.setHealth(20.0);
        player.sendMessage("You have healed " + args[0]);
      }
      else{
        player.setHealth(20.0);
        player.sendMessage("You have been healed");
      }
    }
    else{
      if(args.length > 0){
        Player target = Bukkit.getServer().getPlayer(args[0]);
        target.setHealth(20.0);
        sender.sendMessage("You have healed " + args[0]);
      }
      else{
        sender.sendMessage("Correct usage: /heal <player>");
      }
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: NO I DO NOT HAVE THAT PROBLEM i do have everything. everything works in the game but not the console... Here is the error...

Comment: @MartynasSkirmantas In the question you should include your full code and the full error

Comment: Like this? http://pastebin.com/uXHSRTZA. if i remove Player player = (Player) sender; at the top it show error in every command that player is unknown.

Comment: I will check other way. I think i know what you have in mind.

Comment: @MartynasSkirmantas You can only create the `player` variable once you check `if(sender instanceof Player`. If the sender isn't a player, use `sender.sendMessage()` and give them an error

Comment: Yes it solved kinda.. i have 1 command the contactowner. I do this:

if(sender instanceof Player)
Player player = (Player) sender; <-- ERROR
player.sendmess.....

How do i fix the error? in the command Player player is marked red. I don't want to change player. to sender.

Comment: Use `if(sender instanceof Player){Player player = (Player) sender; player.sendMessage("message");}` and you won't get any errors

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of it, I believe you never got this working. And if you didn't, you can set it up like this:

```
// configure variables.

ConsoleSender console = getServer().getConsoleSender();
Player target = getServer().getPlayer(args[0]);
String[] commands = {"heal"};

if(command.getLabel().equalsIgnoreCase(commands[0])){
    // this checks to see if the sender, is the console.
    if(sender == console){                 
        target.setHealth(20.0);
        target.sendMessage("healed by " + sender.getDisplayName());
    }
    return true;                                               
}
```

Comment: Could you please [edit] in an explanation of why this code answers the question? Code-only answers are [discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/148272/274165), because they don't teach the solution.

Comment: Sure thing. Just as soon as I get to my computer.